# Checking for and then deleting an object in an NSSet

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsset

I have an `NSSet` that contains four `NSString`s. If I call `-containsObject:` to see if the `NSSet` contains a certain string, is it possible to delete the entry in the `NSSet` that is equal to the string that I just checked?

If my question makes no sense, it may be because using a `NSSet` may be the wrong way to approach this.

I have four `NSStrings` and would like to put them in some sort of group (Set, Array, etc.). I then want to check if another `NSString` matches any of the `NSString`s in the group. If there is a match between the `NSString` and a `NSString` inside the group, I want to be able to delete the `NSString` match inside the group. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Please don't change the meaning of your question so drastically after you've already recieved answers for the original version. It's fine to ask the `NSMutableArray` version as a separate question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's say your set is `*mySet` and the object you want to remove is `objectToRemove`. Then you can do this:

```
NSMutableSet *mutableSet = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:mySet];
[mutableSet removeObject:objectToRemove];
mySet = mutableSet;
```

Comment: I have created a `NSMutableArray` instead of a `NSSet` because I would like to keep duplicates. Is there a way to use `removeObject:objectToRemove` but only remove the first occurrence in the Array? Thanks

Comment: If you know the address of the object you can use removeObjectIdenticalTo: method

Comment: @acidic it sounds like you want an NSCountedSet then

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `NSMutableSet` and the `removeObject:` method.

Answer (score 1):

Since `NSSets` are immutable you cannot alter them after initialization. Use `NSMutableSet` which has a `removeObject:` method to remove objects

Answer (score 1):

This is not something out of this world and is done quote often by programmers. But instead of NSSet or NSArray you need NSMutableSet or NSMutableArray. Since only mutable collections can be altered after they have been created.

You remove any object from NSMutableArray using.. `[myArray removeObject:yourObject];`

Similarly for NSMutableSet  `[mySet removeObject:yourObject];`

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code on NSMutableArray to remove the first occurrence of the object.

```
[myArray removeObjectAtIndex:[myArray indexOfObject:myObject];
```

Comment: This works great except for when `myObject` does not exist in `myArray`. How can I implement a check to make sure `myObject` is part of `myArray`?

Comment: You can use the following code. NSUInteger myIndex = [myArray indexOfObject:myObject]; if (myIndex != NSNotFound) { [myArray removeObjectAtIndex:myIndex]; }